# How to send apple push notification in mule 3.9.1?

Tags: http, apple-push-notifications, mule, mule-studio

I am using apple push connector.

I get the following error:

```
    INFO  2019-04-15 17:12:50,934 [Thread-11] com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl: Exception while waiting for error code
java.io.IOException: Unexpected command byte 0
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl$1MonitoringThread.run(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:118) ~[mule-module-apple-push-4.1.0.jar:?]
DEBUG 2019-04-15 17:12:50,955 [[api-gateway].standardHTTPS.worker.01] org.mule.module.http.internal.HttpMessageLogger: LISTENER
HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 15 Apr 2019 22:12:50 GMT
```

How to resolve this and get the connector to work?

Thanks

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns

http://mulesoft.github.io/apple-push-connector/mule/apple-push.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used pushy library instead and could successfully send apple push notification.